# Json en div al final devuelve null

Tags: php, json

Resulta que tengo una validación de fechas por medio de un formulario, lo envio por AJAX si el SELECT me da >0 es que ya tengo registros y los muestro en el modal de lo contrario realizo el INSERT. Todo funciona bien hasta que muestro los datos, obtengo el Json y realizo un foreach y envio por AJAX con echo a un DIV, " El problema es que me muestra al final de la información null. si le pongo return 0; me devuelve el "0" al final. Adjunto el codigo.
Quizas hay otra manera mas simple de mostrar e resultado en el modal.

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE (start=? OR start<? AND end>? OR start>? AND start< ?) AND id_Alojamiento=?";
        
        $query=$conexion->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ssssss',$start,$start,$start,$start,$end,$id);                      
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->get_result();
        $query->close();
        
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $datos=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        //return $datos;
            echo '<div class="card">';
         foreach ($datos as $key) {         
        echo '
        <p class="card-title">Reserva INGRESA '.$key['start'].' Salida '.$key['end'].'</p><br>';
        }   
        echo '</div>';
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:$('#frmAgregarAlojamiento').serialize(),
    url:"controlador/c_Agregar_Alojamiento.php",
    success:function(r){
        console.log(r);
        if(r==1){
            
            swal({
                  title: "Guardado Correctamentes",
                  icon: "success",
                })
            /*var codigoReserva = codigoAleatorio(chars, 9);
            $(".codigoReserva").html(codigoReserva);*/
            $('#frmAgregarAlojamiento')[0].reset();
            $('#frmAgregarAlojamiento').modal('hide');
    
        }else{
            swal({
                  title: "Fallo al Ingresar",
                  icon: "error",
                })
        }
        
    }

});
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si el resultado lo muestro, la manera en que verifique con if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ es si la consulta tiene registro si hay lo muestro.El resultado pasa por el controlador y por medio de AJAX lo envia a la vista.

Este es mi controlador

```
<?php
require_once "../modelo/m_Alojamientos.php";

$datos = array(
 "nombre" => $_POST['nombre'],
 "precioA" => $_POST['precioA'],
 "precioP" => $_POST['precioP'],
 "moneda" => $_POST['moneda'],
 "status" => $_POST['status'],
 "alojamiento" => $_POST['alojamiento'], 
 "localidad" => $_POST['localidad'],
 "personas" => $_POST['personas'],
 "mascota" => $_POST['mascota'],
 "dormitorios" => $_POST['dormitorios'],
 "banos" => $_POST['banos'],
 "direccion" => $_POST['direccion'],
 "publicidad" => $_POST['publicidad'],
 "lat" => $_POST['lat'],
 "lon" => $_POST['lon'],
 "camaS" => $_POST['camaS'],
 "camaD" => $_POST['camaD'],
    );


$Alojamiento = new Alojamiento();
echo $Alojamiento->agregarAlojamiento($datos);
?>
```

El "null" es el que aparece abajo en la imagen que adjunte.
Por la lógica no le estaría retornando por eso al colocar return "lo que fuera siempre al final devuelve lo que coloque".

Otra opción que hice fue retornar return $datos, Eso me devuelve un json validos en el DIV de la vista pero en cadena, no se como tomarlo convertirlo y ahí recorrerlo
Adjunto la imagen cuando realizo Return $datos. ese json lo comprobe es valido pero lo recibo en cadena.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que se asigna ahí donde muestra `null`? ¿Qué debería mostrar? Evítanos tener que analizar / adivinar la lógica del código.

Comment: Esto ya salta a la vista: `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){`, en ese contexto `$result` no es un objeto que puedes pasar como parámetro a `mysqli_num_rows`, esa función espera un statement, pero `$result` es un conjunto de resultados ya leídos. Puedes verificar así: `if($result){` Te recomiendo que leas siempre la documentación de la funciones, por ejemplo, [el Manual dice claramente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) qué funciones te devuelven objetos aptos para usar con `mysqli_num_rows`, y `get_result()` no está entre ellas.